# How to find "a href" tag inside a List View in asp.net using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, anchor, href

I need to find `anchor` tag in side a `<asp:ListView>` using jquery.
Sample code is given below.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstview" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
   <td class="col-item-actions">
    <a id="aShare" runat="server" href="#modal-share" class="button button-small modal-trigger">Share</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I need to find the `anchor` tag and change its `href` dynamically using jquery.

Can any body please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: `Listview` has multiple rows which have multiple anchor tags. Do you want to change _all_ href?

Comment: Can you show us the rendered html instead of the aspx?

Comment: @mshsayem : yes i need to change all href.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#'<%=ListView.ClientID %>'").find("a").attr("href","srt your href");
```

reference **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Comment: The rendered listview will not have that ID.  That's an asp.net ID, not a client ID.

Comment: Also, there won't be any `a` tag with id `aShare`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have classes assigned. You could try:

```
$("#<%= lstview.ClientID %> .button").attr("href","yourhref");
```

or

```
$("#<%= lstview.ClientID %> .button-small").attr("href","yourhref");
```

Notice the `lstview.ClientID` because this is dynamically generated id.